# Xamarin CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions

Tags: sorting, listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

Im looking at porting a wpf application over to Xamarin.Forms

The WPF application contains a ListView which has been sorted using, CollectionViewSource.SortDescription

Is there an equivalent to the above available in Xamarin.Forms.
I have a ListView thats bound to a ObservableCollection. Ideally id like to be able to sort the list in a similar manor

Answer (score -1):

There are no properties like that, but it's easy to do this with Linq.